# Customizing options_for_select output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `select_tag` with `options_for_select` that looks like this:

```
<%= select_tag "respondent", options_for_select(1..5, 2) %>
```

That outputs:

```
<select id="respondent" name="respondent">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

But what I want it to output is this:

```
<select id="respondent" name="respondent">
  <option value="/arbitrary/page/1">#1</option>
  <option value="/arbitrary/page/2" selected="selected">#2</option>
  <option value="/arbitrary/page/3">#3</option>
  <option value="/arbitrary/page/4">#4</option>
  <option value="/arbitrary/page/5">#5</option>
</select>
```

How can I pull that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have such named route like `arbitrary_page_path`:

```
<% collection = (1..5).map { |i| ["##{i}", arbitrary_page_path(i)] } %>
<%= select_tag "respondent", options_for_select(collection, arbitrary_page_path(2)) %>
```